# Drupal execution memory limit in hosting provider

Tags: php, drupal, hosting, memory-limit

We developed the Drupal based portal. After the testing and deployment (in locally) the site was working perfectly. But when I move the site to the online server (hosting), the site was facing the memory execution limit problem.

It's expecting minimum 96MB but the hosting provider is not able to increase that much!! Is any other way to fix this issue?? Or in Australia any other hosting provider is giving this much memory limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, 96MB is a lot for a Drupal site to require. Look over the modules you have installed on the site and disable and uninstall anything you don't actually need. For example, disable the core Color and Comment modules (enabled by default in Drupal 6), if you're not using them. If you have module like Views UI, Beautytips UI, ImageCache UI, or Rules Administration UI intalled, disable them once you're done configuring everything.

If there are only specific pages that are requiring too much memory, try optimizing those pages. For example, if there are lots of nodes being displayed in a view, try adding a pager to the view, to split the content across multiple pages.

If you have custom modules, try separating out the administrative UI code into a separate modulename.admin.inc file, so it will only be loaded when needed. Heck, consider doing that for publicly contributed modules too, then consider posting patches to the issue queues of those modules.

**UPDATE**: You may want to consider VPS hosting next. There you'll have more control over the system you're running on.

**UPDATE 2**: Depending on the needs and features of your site, you may be able to reduce your site's memory footprint by installing the [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) module, which creates a flat-file version of your site.

Comment: I really need all the plugins. So no way to disable any modules from the current system!! Is any other way to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I have to check all the options you mentioned.